# Count distinct values from subquery using TO_CHAR(date,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24') hourly

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to get the distinct values from one column for a day and group the sum using different   column by hour using to_char.
For Example:

```
select to_char(date,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24'),count(*) from select distinct(name) from table_name  
where date > to_date(some_date_format)  
and date < to_date(some_date_format)  
group by to_char(date,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24')  
order by 1
```

Result Example:
01.01.01 01 233
01.01.01 02 233
01.01.01 03 233
01.01.01 04 233
01.01.01 05 233

I get the result hourly but without the distinct column 'name' values from the subquery.
Can somebody explain me where is my mistake.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post an example result set you would like to see the query return.  That can help clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
CREATE TABLE  table_name (name, my_date) AS 
(
SELECT 'foo', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2021 14:30','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2021 14:30','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2021 14:30','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'foo', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2021 15:35','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
);

table created 


SELECT TO_CHAR(my_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24') as "date",
       name, 
       count(*)  
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(my_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24'), 
       name;

date                    NAM   COUNT(*)
----------------------- --- ----------
01-JAN-2021 15          foo          1
01-JAN-2021 14          foo          1
01-JAN-2021 14          bar          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning the number of distinct names (it's using the COUNT command), not the list of names, as you may want it to do.

Because you're grouping the results by timestamp, you'll have at maximum 1 row for each timestamp, so you need to show the distinct names in a single row.

I suggest you to use Oracle's LISTAGG command to do that -- see the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Grouping data from different rows into a single row is not part of the standard SQL specification, so each SQL manufacturer will have its own implementation of this function (or even it won't have, sometimes).

Also, keep in mind that, because this list can grow, it can end up with some performance issues (some manufacturers will need you to set some buffer parameters in order to accomodate this calculated data into a single column).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.

I found my mistake:

```
select 
    to_char(date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24'), count(distinct name)
from 
    table_name  
where
    date > to_date(some_date_format)  
    and date < to_date(some_date_format)  
group by 
    to_char(date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24')    
order by 1
```

When I use `count(distinct name)`, it counts all distinct name values hourly.

I was doing it wrong in the beginning using subquery.